# How to automatically remove product attribute when module is disable/removed

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, magento2.3.5

Hi am working on a custom module that works based on custom product attribute. below is the code of **installdata.php** file

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'no_free_shipping',
                [
                    'group' => 'General',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'label' => 'no_free_shipping',
                    'input' => 'boolean',
                    'class' => '',
                    'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '1',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,bundle'
                ]
            );

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'no_flat_rate',
                [
                    'group' => 'General',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'label' => 'no_flat_rate',
                    'input' => 'boolean',
                    'class' => '',
                    'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '1',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,bundle'
                ]
            );


            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'no_table_rate',
                [
                    'group' => 'General',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'label' => 'no_table_rate',
                    'input' => 'boolean',
                    'class' => '',
                    'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '1',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,bundle'
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

What i want is to remove/unassigned these attributes automatically when the magento module is removed or disable but unfortunately am  not able to find a solution for this.
any suggestion please guide THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unistall` script to remove/unassigned the attributes automatically when the magento module is uninstalled.

To uninstall any module in magento, we use the below command :

```
$ magento module:uninstall [--backup-code] [--backup-media] [--backup-db] [-r|--remove-data] [-c|--clear-static-content] \
  {ModuleName} ... {ModuleName}
```

where `{ModuleName}` specifies the module name in `<VendorName>_<ModuleName>` format

If `--remove-data` is specified, removes the database schema and data defined in the module’s Uninstall classes.

Check the docs for more details :
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html#instgde-cli-uninst-mod-uninst

So this indicates for a module to run a script at uninstall, the module should be uninstalled using the --remove-data option, or shorthand -r. So if the users of your module do not use that option, the script won't run.

Create `Uninstall.php` at path `app/code/Company/MyModule/Setup/Uninstall.php`

```
<?php

namespace Company\MyModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Db\Select;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface as UninstallInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Class Uninstall
 */
class Uninstall implements UninstallInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $_eavSetupFactory;
    
    private $_mDSetup;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $mDSetup
    )
    {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->_mDSetup = $mDSetup;
    }

    public function uninstall(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        /** @var AdapterInterface $connection */
        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        $connection->dropTable('hella_test'); // remove table hella_test

        $installer->endSetup();

        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->_mDSetup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'test_uninstall'); // removing the installed attribute
    }
}
```

**NOTE** : Uninstall command works only with a module installed using a composer or defined as Composer packages.